# Ho to stop SSMS from reverting font settings

Tags: ssms, configuration

(Is this the correct forum for this question?)

I teach Microsoft SQL for a training organisation. For teaching purposes, we’re using SQL Server Express and SSMS.

I don’t like some of the defaults in SSMS, so I put some effort into changing some of the settings. In particular, I prefer to change the font name and size for the text editor, the text results and the grid. I do this with every new class, since the machines are reimaged.

Anybody who’s changed the grid fonts in particular will know that it’s the most tedious part, requiring one or more restarts.

To make life less miserable, I automate the process by copying across a settings file which was originally exported from a working setup. I have also set up a specific settings file just for the font, so it’s easy to import that and apply the new fint settings.

Here’s the problem. The next day, the grid font typically reverts to the original font and size. Sometimes that also happens to the text fonts. We re-import the font settings file, but that shouldn’t be necessary.

I also find that If I try to set the font using the normal Tools Options method and restart when prompted that it sometimes forgets the font settings. I sometimes need to do this a few times.

Does anybody know what’s causing SSMS to be so flaky with the font settings. I’ve tried with SSMS 17 (aka 14, of course) and SSMS 18. I haven’t used SSMS 19 enough to be sure about that.

Comment: You should ensure you're using the latest minor version of either SSMS 18 or 19 minimally.